# BURN (WIX bootstrapper) - files in use dialog not being shown

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I have created a WIX msi for one of our products which works really well. The product is a Word addin and at upgrade/uninstall the msi automatically checks if Word is open (ie. my assemblies are currently locked in execution) and if it is, then it comes up with the Files In Use dialog.

The only improvement I would like to make is at installation time. I would like to check whether word is open and force close before install. It would be great to do so, using the same Files In Use UI. Is there an easy way to do this?

I have also created a custom bootstrapper (unmanaged), using the sample code from the toolset. Overall this is really good too, however I have real problems when upgrading/uninstalling. Ideally, I don’t want to DisplayInternalUI but I would like the Files In Use to pop up when necessary. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feature request [4382](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4382/) was implemented and is available in v3.10.0.1726.  Set `ShowFilesInUse` to `yes` in the [`WixStandardBootstrapperApplication`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/wixstandardbootstrapperapplication.html) element.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know